# git pull hangs at the end of pulling intermittently

Tags: git, http, github

I add remote repository

```
git remote add -f origin <URL>
```

then pull

```
git pull origin <branch>
```

Code resides in our corporate server.
In most occasions git pull successfully returns. But on some occasions it hangs after pulling code from repository.

```
-> git pull origin <branch>
    From <URL>
    * branch            <branch name> -> FETCH_HEAD
    Already up-to-date.   <=== **hanging now at git pull, does not return**
```

I have disabled ssl verification.
My configs looks as below

```
cat ~/.gitconfig
[http]
        sslcainfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
        sslVerify = false
[core]
        autocrlf = true
[color]
        ui = true
[user]
        name = <name>
        email = <email>
[credential]
        helper = cache --timeout 7200
```

I tried pulling with git debug on

```
> GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull origin <branch>
```

there isn't any difference between a successful git pull and a non returning one. In fact its not an issue with git pull, its hanging after a successful pull.

What could cause this intermittent issue? How can I debug this?

Comment: Are you on Windows in a git bash? Or on Linux/mac? What is your Git version? Does git fetch hangs too?

Comment: Im using in solaris and Linux version is 1.8.4.2

Comment: Any possibility to compile and install a more recent Git (2.11)?

Comment: well that's highly unlikely to happen any time soon. upgrades have to go through several levels of approvals.